# Get ID of related object

Tags: django, django-models

```
class ModelA(...):
   modelB = ForeignKey(...)
```

Say I have `modelA` instance, how do I get the ID of  `modelA.modelB` without incurring a DB query?

If I do `modelA.modelB.pk` it will send a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `modelA.modelB_id`. That uses the underlying db field directly.